# target pattern contains no '%'. Stop. When using $(shell sh -c "./ " ) (current working directory)

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I've been working on a Makefile, and have discovered what seems like a strange bug, I have two executeables in my directory that I am building then running:

`TARGETS = sr_flipflop_clk_async_rst_tb sr_flipflop_tb`

The error occurs in my `test` target, where the following code resides:

```
    $(foreach src, $(TARGETS), \
        printf '\033[33m'; \
        echo "Running tests on target" $(src); \
        printf '\033[39m'; \
        $(eval $(shell sh -c "echo \"Results\" >> ../output/${src}.out")) \
        $(eval $(shell ./${src})))
```

The error is generated from this line:
`$(eval $(shell ./${src})))`

For some reason, the error only occurs when the target is `sr_flipflop_tb` but not on the second target. The error also does not occur if i remove the dot indicating the current working directory. I have tried a workaround by changing the line to:
`$(eval $(shell ../build/${src})))` (current directory is called build)

This also generates the error. I cant for the life of me figure out why this is occurring, the error generated is:

`Makefile:28: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.`

where line 28 refers to the beginning of the `test` target.

Any idea what's going on here? I could understand if maybe a bug occured that was not liking the single dot, but the fact that i cant jump up a directory then back into this directory is puzzling to say the least, and the fact that it only occurs on one of my targets. Hoping someone can help me out with this.

In case it would be helpful, here is my directory structure:

```
.
|-- build
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- e~sr_flipflop_clk_async_rst_tb.o
|   |-- e~sr_flipflop_tb.o
|   |-- gather_errors.sh
|   |-- hello.txt
|   |-- sed.out
|   |-- sr_flipFlop.o
|   |-- sr_flipFlop_clk_async_rst.o
|   |-- sr_flipFlop_clk_async_rst_tb.o
|   |-- sr_flipFlop_tb.o
|   |-- sr_flipflop_clk_async_rst_tb
|   |-- sr_flipflop_tb
|   `-- work-obj93.cf
|-- output
|   |-- cat_test.out
|   |-- sr_flipflop_clk_async_rst_tb.out
|   `-- sr_flipflop_tb.out
```

Thanks,
EJ

Edit: Apparently if I change the name of `sr_flipflop_tb` to literally anything else, it works. Can someone tell me what's going on here? It literally has to do with the name of this specific file.

Comment: I have also noticed that when I change the offending line to:
`$(shell sh -c "./${src}" ) )`
I get a different error: 
`/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Makefile:28: recipe for target 'test' failed`

Comment: You are using make functions (`foreach`, `eval`, `shell`) in a make recipe while make recipes are normally shell scripts. This is really weird. Independently from your error, you should first use make in a more _standard_ way. For instance, `$(eval $(shell ./${src})))` does not make sense at all. And, by the way, you should give us more information: as the error says it has to do with the target pattern but you show only the recipe, not the target. We cannot help without a full understanding.

Answer (score 0):

That code is wrong.  You should not use `$(eval ...)` because it expects to be given makefile syntax (rules and makefile variable settings).

Since you're giving it the output of a shell command, it's invalid.  I suspect that the shell command you're running is somehow generating an error message or something.

Second, you shouldn't use `$(shell ...)` because all make variables and functions are expanded FIRST, before ANY other commands are run.  This means all your invocations of `$(shell ...)` will happen, then the printfs will all happen.

You should be using shell syntax for this, not make syntax.  You can use make's foreach if you really want to:

```
$(foreach src, $(TARGETS), \
    printf '\033[33m'; \
    echo "Running tests on target" $(src); \
    printf '\033[39m'; \
    echo "Results" >> ../output/${src}.out; \
    ./${src};)
```

or you can write it with a shell loop:

```
for src in $(TARGETS); do \
    printf '\033[33m'; \
    echo "Running tests on target $$src"; \
    printf '\033[39m'; \
    echo "Results" >> "../output/$$src.out"; \
    "./$$src"; \
done
```

But really, this is HIGHLY non-make-like.  Looping inside of recipes is virtually always a bad idea.  You should instead use make's rules to do this right:

```
test: $(addprefix test-,$(TARGETS))

test-%:
        @printf '\033[33m'; \
        echo "Running tests on target" $*; \
        printf '\033[39m'; \
        echo "Results" >> ../output/$*.out; \
        ./$*
```

Comment: I fixed up the shell invocation; I guess you meant to use `$$src` rather than `${src}` or `$(src)` (sic) throughout, but please review.