# How to loop trough counter in GNU makefile?

Tags: for-loop, gnu-make, buildroot

What would be a proper way of defining a number macro in Config.in and looping through it in makefile?

Config.in

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_CNT
    string "counter"
    default "1" if BR2_PLATFORM_XX
    default "2" if BR2_PLATFORM_YY
```

package.mk

```
$(foreach i, $(shell seq $(BR2_PACKAGE_CNT)), \
    $(info $i))
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use the 3rd example in [https://stackoverflow.com/a/65008659](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65008659).

Comment: @urcodebetterznow Not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think you mean _through_ not _trough_.  However I have no idea what you're trying to do.  Maybe if you provided an example of the results you want it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With some examples I manage to construct a number list from Boolean variable, which then could be iterated. Maybe not the cleanest approach, but the best I could come up with.

Defined in Config.in

```
config CONFIG_VAR_1
  bool "var 1"
  default y

config CONFIG_VAR_2
  bool "var 2"
  default y
```

Makefile

```
VAR = \
    $(if $(CONFIG_VAR_1), 0) \
    $(if $(CONFIG_VAR_2), 1)

$(foreach i, $(VAR), $(info VAR=$i))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `interval` in [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-intervalstartrangestep) which creates a list of numbers.

```
include gmtt.mk

$(foreach i, $(call interval,1,$(BR2_PACKAGE_CNT)), \
    $(info $i))
```